# Merging sub-group values using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to concatenate a Accounting order number should be first in output file based on group of transactions.
Input file

```
01 2019-03-01 Travel     1500 DCA CR
04 2019-03-01 Allowance   300 ATC DR
05 2019-03-02 Local Trip  100 TCO CR
             Accounting Order 190291

22 2019-02-01 Charges     2500 DCA CR
98 2019-02-08 Allowance    900 ATC DR
36 2019-01-30 Local Trip    50 TCO CR
74 2019-02-09 Court fees   300 ATC DR
             Accounting Order 195297

33 2019-03-01 Travel     1500 DCA CR
97 2019-03-01 Allowance   300 ATC DR
             Accounting Order 180876
```

Output should be

```
190291 01 2019-03-01 Travel     1500 DCA CR
190291 04 2019-03-01 Allowance   300 ATC DR
190291 05 2019-03-02 Local Trip  100 TCO CR
195297 22 2019-02-01 Charges     2500 DCA CR
195297 98 2019-02-08 Allowance    900 ATC DR
195297 36 2019-01-30 Local Trip    50 TCO CR
195297 74 2019-02-09 Court fees   300 ATC DR
180876 33 2019-03-01 Travel     1500 DCA CR
180876 97 2019-03-01 Allowance   300 ATC DR
```

Is there a way to concatenate account number values like that?  Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What is your original format? there are 3 different files or dataframes?

Comment: Single source file

Comment: OK, but your file has no delimiters? The Accounting Order is on with column?

Comment: yes. I will use pd.read_fwf for loading. Accounting order would be 5th or 6th column

Comment: Is this exact the reproduction of your file? And if possible, the code you are using to read, so the solution can be executed without errors and assumptions.

Comment: Yes, exact from production mainframe file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [pd.read_fwf()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) as required and the [fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with method backfill:

```
# reads the file with positional reference
cols = [(0,2),(2,13),(14,24),(25,29),(30,34),(34,37)]
names = ['id','date','desc','value','type1','type2']
df = pd.read_fwf('my_file_22.txt', header=None, colspecs = cols, names = names)

# creates the new column
df['Accounting Order'] = df[df.desc == 'Accounting']['type1'] + df[df.desc == 'Accounting']['type2']
nans = (df.desc == 'Accounting') | df.id.isna()
df = df.fillna(method='backfill')
df = df[~nans]
```

It produces the following output:

```
    id      date        desc        value   type1   type2   Accounting Order
0   1.0     2019-03-01  Travel      1500    DCA     CR      190291
1   4.0     2019-03-01  Allowance   300     ATC     DR      190291
2   5.0     2019-03-02  Local Trip  100     TCO     CR      190291
5   22.0    2019-02-01  Charges     2500    DCA     CR      195297
6   98.0    2019-02-08  Allowance   900     ATC     DR      195297
7   36.0    2019-01-30  Local Trip  50      TCO     CR      195297
8   74.0    2019-02-09  Court fees  300     ATC     DR      195297
11  33.0    2019-03-01  Travel      1500    DCA     CR      180876
12  97.0    2019-03-01  Allowance   300     ATC     DR      180876
```

**Observations:**

1) considered the positional reading, what caused some issues once the columns are not with the same width;

2) the data considered for the solutions was:

```
01 2019-03-01 Travel     1500 DCA CR
04 2019-03-01 Allowance   300 ATC DR
05 2019-03-02 Local Trip  100 TCO CR
              Accounting Order 190291

22 2019-02-01 Charges    2500 DCA CR
98 2019-02-08 Allowance   900 ATC DR
36 2019-01-30 Local Trip   50 TCO CR
74 2019-02-09 Court fees  300 ATC DR
              Accounting Order 195297

33 2019-03-01 Travel     1500 DCA CR
97 2019-03-01 Allowance   300 ATC DR
              Accounting Order 180876
```

Answer (score 1):

For example with the following code (which is basically splitting all lines into two lists `z[0]` and `z[1]` based on whether they contain 'Accounting order' or not, and then does `read_fwf` on non-Accounting-order lines from `z[0]`, while adding `bfill`ed Accounting Order numbers from the Accounting-order list `z[1]`):

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    s = f.read()

z = list(zip(*[(x.split('Accounting Order')[1], '') if 'Accounting Order' in x
               else (np.nan, x)
               for x in s.splitlines()]))

df = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(z[0], columns=['Accounting Order']).bfill(),
    pd.read_fwf(pd.compat.StringIO('\n'.join(z[1])), header=None)], 1).dropna()

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Accounting Order     0           1           2            3
0            190291   1.0  2019-03-01      Travel  1500 DCA CR
1            190291   4.0  2019-03-01   Allowance   300 ATC DR
2            190291   5.0  2019-03-02  Local Trip   100 TCO CR
5            195297  22.0  2019-02-01     Charges  2500 DCA CR
6            195297  98.0  2019-02-08   Allowance   900 ATC DR
7            195297  36.0  2019-01-30  Local Trip    50 TCO CR
8            195297  74.0  2019-02-09  Court fees   300 ATC DR
11           180876  33.0  2019-03-01      Travel  1500 DCA CR
12           180876  97.0  2019-03-01   Allowance   300 ATC DR
```